# Get single array from array of array in mongoose aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a collection like this (That I got from last pipeline condition):

```
[
{_id:"1","field":[{...obj1},{...obj2}]},
{_id:"2","field":[{...obj3},{...obj1}]},
{_id:"3","field":[{...obj4},{...obj5}]},
{_id:"4","field":[{...obj1},{...obj2}]},
]
```

I want to add more conditions in the pipeline to get :

```
[{...obj1},{...obj2},{...obj3},{...obj4},{...obj5}]
```

The order doesn't matter but I want all the objects from `field`. I am new to mongo and mongoose, so I don't know which aggregation property will work here.

Please help me, I think it is a simple task but I am unable to do so because of lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to deconstruct `field` array,
- [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to replace `field` object to root

```
{ $unwind: "$field" },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$field" } }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5E0Z3I7S3Lk)

---

For unique object try `$group` stage after `$unwind` stage,

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$field.name",
      field: { $first: "$field" }
    }
  },
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3pIgDa6vZSe)

Comment: don't bother about downvoting, just follow instruction on [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question,

Comment: actually I also wanted only unique objects (like I have shown in Example) which I implemented using $group and $addToSet. I hope you will update the answer using this so that others can be helped too : )